# How can one verify whether consecutive letters have been entered from the qwerty keyboard in a delphi console application?

Tags: delphi, console-application, password-checker

Basically, I have an input and I want to verify whether the user input has used 3 or more consecutive letters from the qwerty keyboard layout. By this I mean Q-W-E or Y-U-I-O-P. First I stored the user input in a string variable and used the  ansiLowerCase function to convert the input to lowercase. I messed around with declaring the qwerty layout as a constant string and using the strscan function but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There was a virtually identical q posted here two days ago and later deleted.  Is this a coursework task which you have been set?

Comment: Actually I was trying to extend a program I was doing from a coding challenge booklet. It was from this website: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pbdiI9H_RiUkl0cXcySUJCOTg/view and was task 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function HasThreeConsecutiveLetters(const Str: string): Boolean;
const
  QwertyLetters: array[0..2] of string = (
    'QWERTYUIOP',
    'ASDFGHJKL',
    'ZXCVBNM'
  );
var
  I, J, K: Integer;
  S: String;
begin
  Result := False;
  S := AnsiUpperCase(Str);
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    for J := Low(QwertyLetters) to High(QwertyLetters) do
    begin
      K := Pos(S[I], QwertyLetters[J]);
      if (K <> 0) and
         ((K+2) <= Length(QwertyLetters[J])) and
         (Copy(S, I, 3) = Copy(QwertyLetters[J], K, 3)) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
var
  input: string;
begin
  input := ...;
  if HasThreeConsecutiveLetters(input) then
    ...
  else
    ...
end;
```